# Partial derivative of order 2 of an definite integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So the rule for partial derivatives of a higher order is to go from right to left. But i can't solve this one:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}\int^x_1 \exp\left(\frac{x+y}{t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Can someone explain to me in steps or give me a formula which can be used?

The result has to be
$$\int^x_1\frac{1}{t^2} \exp\left(\frac{x+y}{t}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t +\frac{1}{x} \exp\left(\frac{x+y}{x}\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Leibniz rule of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement), which tells how to exchange partial derivative and integral sign, and how to treat the integral boundary expressions if they overlap with the derivative operations.

In detail:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}
\int\limits_1^x e^{(x+y)/t} \, dt  
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\int\limits_1^x e^{(x+y)/t} \, dt \\
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\int\limits_1^x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} e^{(x+y)/t} \, dt \\
&=
\int\limits_1^x 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} e^{(x+y)/t} \, dt +
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} e^{(x+y)/x} \cdot \frac{dx}{dx}
\\
&=
\int\limits_1^x 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{(x+y)/t} (1/t) \, dt +
e^{(x+y)/x} \cdot (1/x)
\\
&=
\int\limits_1^x 
e^{(x+y)/t} (1/t^2) \, dt +
e^{(x+y)/x} \cdot (1/x) \quad (*) \\
&=
-\frac{1}{x+y}
\left[ 
e^{(x+y)/t} 
\right]_{t=1}^{t=x} +
e^{(x+y)/x} \cdot (1/x) \\
&=
\frac{1}{x+y} \left(
e^{x+y} -
e^{(x+y)/x} 
\right)
+
e^{(x+y)/x} \cdot (1/x) \\
\end{align}

where $(*)$ agrees with your result.